# Apache Flume: kafka.consumer.ConsumerTimeoutException

Tags: apache-kafka, flume, flume-ng

I'm trying to build pipeline with Apache Flume:
spooldir -> kafka channel -> hdfs sink

Events go to kafka topic without problems and I can see them with kafkacat request. But kafka channel can't write files to hdfs via sink. The error is:

**Timed out while waiting for data to come from Kafka**

Full log:

> 2016-02-26 18:25:17,125
>   (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor-SendThread(zoo02:2181))
>   [DEBUG -
>   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.readResponse(ClientCnxn.java:717)]
>   Got ping response for sessionid: 0x2524a81676d02aa after 0ms
>
> 2016-02-26 18:25:19,127
>   (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor-SendThread(zoo02:2181))
>   [DEBUG -
>   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.readResponse(ClientCnxn.java:717)]
>   Got ping response for sessionid: 0x2524a81676d02aa after 1ms
>
> 2016-02-26 18:25:21,129
>   (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor-SendThread(zoo02:2181))
>   [DEBUG -
>   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.readResponse(ClientCnxn.java:717)]
>   Got ping response for sessionid: 0x2524a81676d02aa after 0ms
>
> 2016-02-26 18:25:21,775
>   (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [DEBUG -
>   org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel$KafkaTransaction.doTake(KafkaChannel.java:327)]
>   Timed out while waiting for data to come from Kafka
>   kafka.consumer.ConsumerTimeoutException   at
>   kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator.makeNext(ConsumerIterator.scala:69)
>     at
>   kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator.makeNext(ConsumerIterator.scala:33)
>     at
>   kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.maybeComputeNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:66)
>     at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.hasNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel$KafkaTransaction.doTake(KafkaChannel.java:306)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.take(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:113)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.channel.BasicChannelSemantics.take(BasicChannelSemantics.java:95)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.process(HDFSEventSink.java:374)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
>     at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

My FlUME's config is:

```
# Name the components on this agent
a1.sources = r1
a1.sinks = k1
a1.channels = c2

# Describe/configure the source
a1.sources.r1.type = spooldir
a1.sources.r1.spoolDir = /home/alex/spoolFlume

a1.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path =  hdfs://10.12.0.1:54310/logs/flumetest/
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.filePrefix = flume-
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.round = true
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.roundValue = 10
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.roundUnit = minute
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.writeFormat = Text

a1.channels.c2.type   = org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel
a1.channels.c2.capacity = 10000
a1.channels.c2.transactionCapacity = 1000
a1.channels.c2.brokerList=kafka10:9092,kafka11:9092,kafka12:9092
a1.channels.c2.topic=flume_test_001
a1.channels.c2.zookeeperConnect=zoo00:2181,zoo01:2181,zoo02:2181

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a1.sources.r1.channels = c2
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c2
```

With memory channel instead of kafka channel all works good.

Thanks for any ideas in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue, I too am is stuck at same place, even when I set consumer.timeout.ms through config, it doesnt get overriden and flume continues to work with default of 100 ms

Comment: Nope I didn't find any solution with kafka channel. Memory channel works pretty well and there were no problems during 6 months in production.

Comment: I was able to fix the timeout issue, Kafka Channel code in Flume has hardcoded value set for property consumer.timeout.ms to 100 ms..I fixed the code to read from config instead and the error was gone

Answer (score 0):

ConsumerTimeoutException means there is no new message for a long time, doesn't mean connect time out for Kafka.

http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html

consumer.timeout.ms -1  Throw a timeout exception to the consumer if no message is available for consumption after the specified interval

Comment: Do you mean that I have to change some Kafka properties?
What do you think about pipeline "spooldir -> kafka channel -> hdfs sink" in general? Probably there should be some tricks - another flume instance and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Kafka's ConsumerConfig class has the "consumer.timeout.ms" configuration property, which Kafka sets by default to -1. Any new Kafka Consumer is expected to override the property with a suitable value.

Below is a reference from [Kafka documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/07/configuration.html) :

```
consumer.timeout.ms     -1  
By default, this value is -1 and a consumer blocks indefinitely if no new message is available for consumption. By setting the value to a positive integer, a timeout exception is thrown to the consumer if no message is available for consumption after the specified timeout value.
```

When Flume creates a Kafka channel, it is setting the timeout.ms value to 100, as seen on the Flume logs at the INFO level. That explains why we see a ton of these ConsumerTimeoutExceptions.

```
 level: INFO Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: [agent]
 level: INFO Creating channels
 level: DEBUG Channel type org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel is a custom type
 level: INFO Creating instance of channel c1 type org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel
 level: DEBUG Channel type org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel is a custom type
 level: INFO Group ID was not specified. Using flume as the group id.
 level: INFO {metadata.broker.list=kafka:9092, request.required.acks=-1, group.id=flume, 
              zookeeper.connect=zookeeper:2181, **consumer.timeout.ms=100**, auto.commit.enable=false}
 level: INFO Created channel c1
```

Going by the Flume user guide on [Kafka channel settings](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#kafka-channel), I tried to override this value by specifying the below, but that doesn't seem to work though:

```
agent.channels.c1.kafka.consumer.timeout.ms=5000
```

Also, we did a load test with pounding data through the channels constantly, and this exception didn't occur during the tests.

Comment: yeah. I can confirm that setting option `agent.channels.c1.kafka.consumer.timeout.ms` is useless in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I read flume's source code, and found that flume reads value of the key "timeout" for "consumer.timeout.ms".

So you can config the value for "consumer.timeout.ms" like this:

`agent1.channels.kafka_channel.timeout=-1`